# How to edit a single df element by for loop in R?

Tags: r, loops

sorry for asking dumb questions, but I'm just starting with R.

I want to alter a single df element within a for loop like this:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if(df$var_x[i] == 12345) {
     df$var_y[i] <- 54321}    
}
```

Unfortunately I always get that error message:

```
Error in if (df$var_x[i] == 12345) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

and don't really understand why.
The if clause condition itself should return TRUE/FALSE, shouldn't it?

Comment: You may have missing values i.e. `if(NA == 12345) {TRUE}
Error in if (NA == 12345) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`  Change the `==` to `%in%` or use `& !is.na(df$var_x[i])`.  BTW, these are vectorized operations, i.e. `df$var_y[df$var_x %in% 12345] <- 543211`

Comment: thx a lot, seems to work like that. totally forgot about the NA.

Answer (score 1):

### This is an unnecessary for loop

It would be more conventional and readable to use subsetting:

```r
df[["var_y"]][df[["var_x"]] == 12345] <- 54321
```

That is: "At all the places where `df$var_x` is 12345, make `df$var_y` 54321".